# How to create a simple pause/timeout in scala

Tags: scala, timeout, akka

I am working with some pre existing scala code, and I am trying to execute a specific portion of code after a delay of 30 seconds. Something similar in execution to setTimeout from javascript. What would be the simplest way to do this?

I have been looking at the aka.util.timeout class but I am very new to scala and akka and I am unsure how to implement it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking, but if you are using akka, then you can use [akka schedulers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/scheduler.html).

```
 system.scheduler().scheduleOnce(30 seconds, testActor, "foo");
```

`testActor` will contain your code which will run when the `testActor` receives `foo` message. There are lots of options for scheduler, you can run it once, every 30 seconds or so etc, and also, its will be a non blocking reactive code.